# Text Processing: How to sort list by date delimited by a string

Tags: text-processing, sort, xml, html

I want to sort contents of `file.txt` by date. The date to sort is in the fourth table data `<td></td>` tag

E.g. Content of `file.txt`:

```
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2018Mar01</td></tr>
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2017Jan31</td></tr>
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2018Apr02</td></tr>
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2017Dec25</td></tr>
```

**Desired output:** How can I do this?

```
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2017Jan31</td></tr>
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2017Dec25</td></tr>
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2018Mar01</td></tr>
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2018Apr02</td></tr>
```

I've been using `sort` command but it's not working.

`cat file.txt 2> /dev/null | sort -t'>' -k9n -k9.4M -k9.7n`

**EDIT:** I found this reference link but still doesn't work correctly.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16060031/7842707

Comment: This isn't really text processing, so much as *xml* or *html* processing.

Comment: I'm creating an html file to send as an email. So whenever my recipient receives my email, it is in a form of an html table.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with awk, try a real parser

Comment: Actually `file.txt` is just a text file. It's not the final HTML file. After sorting that out, I'll be redirecting the output to an HTML file. As you can see, there's no HTML tag or table tag in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if each `<tr>` item is on a separate line:

**`awk`** + **`sort`** solution:

```
awk -F'[<>]' '{ print $(NF-4), $0 }' file.txt | sort -k1,1n -k1.5M | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

- `-F'[<>]'` - treat `<` and `>` as field separator
- `$(NF-4)` - contains the last `<td>` tag value (e.g. `2017Jan31`) from each row. This is used as a sorting key.
- `-k1,1n` - sort by the 1st field numerically (i.e. by date year)
- `-k1.5M` - date month sorting starting from the 5th char
- `cut -d' ' -f2-` - remove an auxiliary sorting key (the 1st field)

The output:

```
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2017Jan31</td></tr>
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2017Dec25</td></tr>
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2018Mar01</td></tr>
<tr><td>some_name_here</td><td>number_code_here</td><td>2018Mar31</td><td>2018Apr02</td></tr>
```

Comment: thanks. Do you have some good reference in using `awk` and `sed`? I need to study them more.

Comment: You can do better. Try something with `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//tr/td[3]' -s Y:N:- '.' file` Don't parse HTML with awk

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033820.do, https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: @Gilles Quenot, I'm using Linux. I just wanted to sort the `file.txt` because I'll be redirecting the output to a HTML file to send through email.

Comment: xmlstarlet is a xml/html parser and have sort tricks